# Send data from service to another android app

Tags: android, android-service, intentfilter

I have two android application. One has some services and other application start service. The application activity starts a service and need some data in return from that service. how can I return data from service to the activity start that service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language) to set up the communication between 2 applications.

Comment: Other application has no acttivity thats why I don't think i need AIDL. what do you say ?

Comment: AIDL can be used for communication between activity of an application and service of another one. Actually I was in a similar case and AIDL helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: is it possible to call a **AsyncTask** in your **AIDL** method and wait for **OnPostExecute** method and return **AIDL** method response to main activity ?

Comment: For example: create a AIDL method like this: `int getValue()`. Then you can call `getValue()` in your `AsyncTask` of 1st app. It will call method `getValue()` of the service in the 2nd app and then return an integer.

Comment: no, I connect my service in main project then project calls a method and in this method I have a Asynctask. Let suppose I need to download a file and return its name in response. I will connect my service and then I will call a function downlaodFileAndReturnName() of service Project.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with AIDL